# Kotlin suppress warnings for Receiver parameter is never used

Tags: kotlin, suppress-warnings

So, I have one file where I added extension on some class. Something like

```
val A.extension
    get = 1+1
```

And I get warning *Receiver parameter is never used* that I want to suppress. I tried multiple wild guesses like @file:Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") but nothing worked.

Does someone know which string I am looking for?
Second part of the question: Is there full list of suppress warnings?
Usually there are only hardcoded strings, that I find all over internet, but not list suppress key - suppress description.

EDIT: I know suppress "unused" would do the work, but it is too generic.

EDIT2: I want to suppress specific warning in the whole file, I think it "unused" too generic in way that if I have A.extension and extension is never used, I want it gray(Property unused), but I do not want to have A gray (Receiver parameter unused).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer given above about using `@receiver:Suppress("Unused")` was indeed the best solution until the recent `Android Studio` update.

I found out that `@Suppress("UnusedReceiverParameter")` can be used to achieve the same effect (i.e. suppressing the receiver parameter usage without affecting the unused status of the function itself). Personally, I think this change is for the better as it doesn't interfere with the function signature declaration.

Answer (score 2):

So, I found it finally. It is possible to suppress things just for receiver with adding annotation @receiver:Suppress("Unused")

```
val @receiver:Suppress("Unused") A.extension
    get = 1+1
```

And it will still get grayed out if extension is not used.

Edit: I aded my response before V Mircan answer, but I think his annotation is better.

Answer (score 1):

`@Suppress("unused")` is the best thing to use here. It is not generic in any way.

An `unused property` can only get rid of it's `unused status` by suppressing the `unused inspection`, can't get more specific than that.

The place where I think you are making the mistake, is by suppressing that inspection in the whole file with `@file:Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")`. You need to add the suppression to the extension itself. That way, it won't affect anything else in file.

For example here, `A.extension` will never say unused, but `A.anotherExtension` will do, if it is unused.

```
@Suppress("unused") //comment here if you want to be more explicit
val A.extension
    get() = 1+1

//this one will still say unused if it is unused. 
val A.anotherExtension
    get() = 2+2
```

Comment: I want to suppress specific warning in the whole file, I think it is too generic in way that if I have A.extension and extension is never used, I want it gray(Property unused), but I do not want to have A gray (Receiver parameter unused). If you understood what I want :D

Answer (score 1):

For me, I used

```
@Suppress("UNUSED_ANONYMOUS_PARAMETER")
```